# Ion-content - Having 3 components that have different vertical alignment

Tags: css, ionic-framework, vertical-alignment

I've been struggling in this issue to have in the same ion-view 3 components (these could be buttons, images etc.) that have different vertical alignment (one top, one middle and one bottom).

Here's my codepen example of what I've tried:
h t t p : / / codepen.io/anon/pen/xgYQxO
You can see I've tried to have 3 buttons in a single ion-view and vertically align them differently, but it seems that the buttons are always aligned to top.

How can I achieve this? What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: is it what you want?: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLrVaa

Comment: Yes!! Can you explain what you did?

Comment: I set a `position: absolute` to button-middle and button-bottom, and set corresponding attributes `top` and `bottom` for those elements.  `.button-bottom {
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0;
}`    and   `.button-middle {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);  
}`

Comment: @Banzay please see this: codepen.io/anon/pen/ggvZKp when the components are not full width, the horizontal alignment is a bit funny. How can I horizontally center all three?

Comment: you can add `position: absolute` to all of three ones: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRMLYj

Comment: I put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set absolute position for buttons and set corresponding indents to them:

```
.scroll {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-bottom {
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0;
}

.button-middle {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);  
}

.button-top {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

look at [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRMLYj)